# Couchdb and log4j

Tags: log4j, couchdb

So I am thinking about making the change to couchdb. I googled it but couldn't find any documentation that it would support log4j. What I am trying to do is have a logger send logs to a database and have it store it. From there I want to be able to retrieve the logs and display it. Does couchdb support this?

Comment: What kind of support would you like to see? Please google for CouchDB and log4j integration and update your question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: CouchDB is written in Erlang, not Java. It doesn't run on the JVM. What kind support for log4j are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you need to learn about [couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp) and install [CouchLog](https://github.com/dominicbarnes/CouchLog).

Second you will have to write your own log4j appender to send the log entries in the format that CouchLog expects.

I hacked together a log4j appender that did this a long time ago, the code is lost, don't ask for it. But it was only like 30 mins of coding to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NoSQL appender that supports currently CouchDB and MongoDB:

NoSQLAppender
The NoSQLAppender writes log events to a NoSQL database using an internal lightweight provider interface. Provider implementations currently exist for MongoDB and Apache CouchDB, and writing a custom provider is quite simple. 
(source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)